# Stored procedure execution not in DMVs (sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats, sys.dm_exec_cached_plans)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, dmv

I'm measuring execution time of stored procedures in the database by querying DMV `sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats`.

I found out that some stored procedures are simply not listed in the `sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats`. After investigating it seems that the stored procedures that include a DDL statement (ALTER TABLE, etc.) are simply not cached and therefore not returned from `sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats` or `sys.dm_exec_cached_plans`.

I've observed this behaviour on SQL Server 2008. When I use 2012, the behaviour is different - all the stored procedures seem to be cached and returned from the DMVs. I have not found anything mentioned on the official Microsoft site.

Is there any workaround for this? I would like to get execution statistics (e.g. execution time) of a stored procedure that executes DDL statements...

Comment: I have found this blog post about the same issue: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2010/04/22/a-warning-to-those-using-sys-dm-exec-query-stats.aspx

Comment: So, this seems to be SQL Server 2008 specific issue... Is there any workaround for this? I need to get the execution time of stored procedures what may include DDL statements (e.g. I need a solution that will work on any stored procedure, regardless of its code and that I can easily query from a .NET application)...?

Comment: As a side note, it is not a good practice to mix DDL and DML statements within a stored procedure.  See [Recompilations due to mixing DDL and DML](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee343986(v=sql.100).aspx) from Microsoft Technet.

Comment: Workarounds would include using Profiler or a DDL trigger to capture execution times and log them to a user table.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've solved the issue in the .NET application: I read system date/time when the stored procedure was called and when it was completed. After that I also query the DMVs. If the DMV data does not exist, I use the calculated end-start time, otherwise I use the data from the DMV (it's more precise). Not the nicest solution, but good enough. :)